# Reporting Utilization in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic, resource-utilization

I am looking for some insight into reporting utilization correctly. I am using a time plot that reports `resourceName.utilization()`, additionally, I am also adding the utilization values to a Statistics object every hour. I then plot the mean value of this Statistics object as `statisticName.mean()`. Since utilization in AnyLogic is the returned value is the mean over all individual unit utilization, calculated from the most recent `resetStats()` call up to current time, does reporting the value `statisticName.mean()` even make sense? That would be the average of time averaged values.

Comment: Why not? It gives at high abstraction view. Say, if you have a pool with 3 units and 33% average of averages , it is a reason to investigate it. May be, it has 100 - 0 - 0 load, or 33 - 33 - 33. Both cases require attention and indicate non-optimal workflow. Since AnyLogic allows to get individual statistics, initial 33% is just first high level factor for decision-making.

Comment: Gregory, Thanks for the comment. Maybe I didn't frame my question clearly. Using your example let's say at time 't' all 3 units are 100% utilization. At that point reported utilization will be 100%.  For the duration t1 to t2 they are all idle, so at t2 my utilization will be 50%.  Furthermore, for the duration t2 to t3 they are again all idle, which would mean my utilization is 33%. Does it then make sense to report the mean of (100, 50, 33) = 61%? I think you meant individual unit utilization which is different from what I am after.